# Firebase cloud messaging function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm simply sending a notification when someone new has followed you, but when I try to return the users username in the notification it just says "undefined has decided to follow you" instead of the username.

```
 exports.observeFollowing = functions.database.ref('/following/{uid}/{followingId}').onCreate((snapshot,context) => {
 var uid = context.params.uid;
 var followingId = context.params.followingId;

 console.log('User: ' + uid + 'is following: ' + followingId);

 return admin.database().ref('/users/' + followingId).once('value', snapshot => {

 var userWeAreFollowing = snapshot.val();

 return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {

 var userDoingTheFollowing = snapshot.val();

 var payload = {
   notification: {
     title: "Someone new has followed you",
     body:  userWeAreFollowing.username + " has decided to follow you...",
     sound: 'default'
   }
 }

 admin.messaging().sendToDevice(userWeAreFollowing.fcmToken, payload)
       .then((response) => {
         console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
         return response
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
  })
})
```

[image: Firebase database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
body: userWeAreFollowing.username + " has decided to follow you...",
```

should't be the following user name

```
body: userDoingTheFollowing.usernames + " has decided to follow you...",
```

and notice in your realtime database you saved the username as usernameS, that might be the problem